# MongoDB grouping by month using aggregation timezone issue

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregation structure where it groups the data by month and sums it up on a monthly basis starting from the beginning of the year. At the moment my documents are starting at month 9 and nothing before that.When I run the below aggregation, result shows that data starts from the month 8. I guess it is related to the timezone. Because only 3 hours of data (my timezone is +3) is listed in the month 8.

```
db.collectedData.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $match: {
            _Timestamp: {
                            $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01T21:00:00.000Z"),
                            $lte: ISODate("2019-04-19T01:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "Registers.totalconsumedactiveenergy" : {"$exists" : true}
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $project: {
        "Datem" : "$_Timestamp",
        "month" : {"$month" : "$_Timestamp" },
        "device" : "$_DeviceID",
        "datam" : "$$ROOT.Registers.totalconsumedactiveenergy"
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $group: { 
         "_id": {
                       "Month": "$month",
                       "Device" : "$device"

                },

                first:{$first:"$$ROOT.datam"},
                last: { $last: "$$ROOT.datam" }
        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $project: {
           totalConsumption: { $sum: { $subtract: [ "$last", "$first" ] } },
           month: "$_id.Month"
        }
    },

    // Stage 5
    {
        $group: {
        "_id": "$month", 
        "total": { "$sum": "$totalConsumption" }
        }
    },

    // Stage 6
    {
        $sort: {
        "_id" : 1
        }
    },

]

);
```

This works and gives me results like this
[image: Result Image]

From my application I am sending localtimezone to the aggregation but still no success.

Earliest date in my documents is 
2017-08-31T21:00:00.000Z (UTC)

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can change month to `{
  "month": {
    "$month": {
      "date": "$_Timestamp",
      "timezone": "Europe/Amsterdam"
    }
  }
}` in 3.6

Comment: Above solution perfectly worked after upgrading my mongodb to 3.6.1. Thank you.